# Как начать изучение OpenGL c#

Tags: c#, linux, windows, opengl, opentk

Всем здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать C# OpenTK в интернете очень мало информации по этому.
И соответственно я бы хотел узнать где можно изучить OpenTk.
Буду благодарен всем!

Comment: Про OpenTK не знаю, а про OpenGL [вот](https://learnopengl.com/). (Из-за РКНа может не открыться без прокси, тогда оттуда можно скачать оффлайн-версию в пдф.)

Comment: Спасибо) большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTk - Довольно новый фреймворк, и да по нему довольно мало информации.
Но в целом, это развитие: "Tao Framework"
И по нему гайдов хватает. Например:
http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/
Корелляция этих двух фреймворков достаточна чтобы изучив один, пользоваться другим.

Comment: Да, спасибо, Вам большое)